# Using default_random_engine as a class member and without a class results in different numbers (same seed)

Tags: c++, class, random, class-members

I want to have a separate class for random number generation in my program. I tried to use the `std::default_random_engine`
as a class member and then generate random vectors with functions.
When I compared the results to the generation of random numbers without a class, I noticed that for uneven dimensions one random number in the sequence is skipped.
For example (of course not random):

```
1,2,3 & 5,6,7 & 9,10,11 (sequence with class)
1,2,3 & 4,5,6 & 7, 8, 9 (sequence without class)
```

For even dimensions both sequences are the same. So I tried to make a sample code to illustrate the differences.

In this example I also noticed that, in the case of 4-dim, an additional number is sampled as the first number (for the case without a class). If I use another distribution e.g. uniform, there was not such a difference.

Has somebody an idea what I am doing wrong? Do I maybe initialize the generator to often?

I appreciate any help.

Small example code:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

class RandomGenerator{
  public:
    RandomGenerator(int seed):generator_(seed){}
    void generateGaussian(int dim){
      std::normal_distribution<double> distribution(0.,1.);
      for(int i=0; i<dim;++i){
        std::cout<<distribution(generator_)<<std::endl;
      }
    }
  private:
    std::default_random_engine generator_;
};

int main(){
  std::normal_distribution<double> distribution(0.,1.);

  std::cout<<std::endl<<"With Class - 4dim"<<std::endl;
  RandomGenerator random_generator4=RandomGenerator(912134);

  random_generator4.generateGaussian(4);
  std::cout<<"***"<<std::endl;
  random_generator4.generateGaussian(4);
  std::cout<<"***"<<std::endl;
  random_generator4.generateGaussian(4);

  std::cout<<std::endl<<"Without Class"<<std::endl;
  std::default_random_engine generator4(912134);
  for(int i=0; i<15;++i){
    std::cout<<distribution(generator4)<<std::endl;
    if((i+1)%4==0){
        std::cout<<"***"<<std::endl;
    }
  }

  std::default_random_engine generator(912134);
  RandomGenerator random_generator=RandomGenerator(912134);
  std::cout<<"With Class - 3dim "<<std::endl;
  random_generator.generateGaussian(3);
  std::cout<<"***"<<std::endl;
  random_generator.generateGaussian(3);
  std::cout<<"***"<<std::endl;
  random_generator.generateGaussian(3);


  std::cout<<std::endl<<"Without Class"<<std::endl;
  for(int i=0; i<11;++i){
    std::cout<<distribution(generator)<<std::endl;
    if((i+1)%3==0){
        std::cout<<"***"<<std::endl;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

edit:
I added this to the code. Now the results are exactly the same. I will test the statistical properties to check if the results with reset are still gaussian.

```
if((i+1)%3==0){
    distribution.reset();
    std::cout<<"***"<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `std::default_random_engine`.  It is basically the C++11 equivelent of `rand`.  You should be using something like [`std::mt19937`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine).  Also if you use the same seed ever time you will get the same results.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Of course he gets the same results every time - that's very useful when you are debugging!

Comment: There's something odd going on here!  If you remove the dim=4 code from your sample ... the dim=3 code doesn't miss a value! (So it's not odd/even, but something more subtle.)

Comment: @Martin Bonner  You are right. If I only use the 3dim, they are equal.   
In the larger program it is coupled to odd/even. (But I hope if we/I can understand the sample I can fix it in the larger program too).

Comment: I fear you are going to have to dive into the depths of the implementation of default_random_engine.  (Possibly just putting some debugging prints in would be enough.)

Comment: @NathanOliver If I use the `std::mt19937` the same error occurs.

Comment: @Matrin Bonner Do you think it is the random engine? mt19937 has the same error. Could it be possible that the problem comes from the distribution? The uniform distribution do not have such a problem.

Answer (score 0):

At least within C++11, distributions might have an internal-state, just like PRNGS. (I observed this state to be used at least for the normal-distribution; maybe uniform-dist behaves differently)

Without analyzing your code exactly (hard to read for my lazy python-programming-shaped eye), i can imagine this to be the source of those observations.

So when you init `std::normal_distribution<double> distribution(0.,1.);` at the first line within your main, this object will be used in both *without class* loops and the second one will not start from scratch, as the first one changed the internal state (so seeding your PRNG is not enough).

Your class based approach however inits a fresh distribution when calling `generateGaussian`.

Comment: Nice idea. 
I tried it: `generateGaussian(int dim,std::normal_distribution<double>& distribution)` . This way I define the distribution only once. But the problem persists.

Comment: I looked into it with more detail. The addtional random number is persistent but the skipping is gone with this approach. (I have to test it further)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. This helped to investigate it further. If I reset the distribution everytime, I have the same results. So far I do not understand why I do not have the same results if I have the distribution only defined once in the code.